# IEquatable<T> and [AllowNull]

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I just updated Visual Studio to latest 16.6.0 Preview 1.0 with latest .NET Core 3.1.2. My project has `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`.

It seems there has been a change to `IEquatable<T>` and now it is defined with `[AllowNull]`:

```cs
public interface IEquatable<T>
{
  bool Equals([AllowNull] T other);
}
```

As a result, any class of mine which implemented `IEquatable<T>` with `bool Equals(T o)` now shows a warning:

> `CS8767`: Nullability of reference types in type of parameter 'o' of 'bool MyType.Equals(MyType o)' doesn't match implicitly implemented member 'bool IEquatable.Equals(MyType other)' because of nullability attributes.

What is the best way to solve this ?

I can add a nullable operator `bool Equals(T? o)`, or I can add `[AllowNull]` (with reference to `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis`). Both seem to make the warning go away, but I'm not sure which one is better.

Also, I now opened the door for a `null` parameter which I didn't really want.

Comment: I realized that nullability checking and generics is still a hard living...

Comment: related https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/41937

Comment: Seems like might need to temporarily disable the warning until the bug is fixed. See my answer.

Comment: 'bug' ? 'fixed' ? Do you have any reference for this ?

Comment: Add `[AllowNull]` to your `Equals` method

Comment: Can the you share the entire code sample? With your types implementing `IEquatable<T>`

Comment: Why wasn't the `IEquatable<T>` left without the addition of the nullable attribute? That way we can specify nullable by using `class Foo : IEquatable<T?>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The convention for `IEquatable<T>.Equals` is that the argument can be null. If `T` is a reference type, just annotate it with `?` and the warning will go away. The following compiles just fine:

```cs
#nullable enable

using System;

public class C1 : IEquatable<C1>
{
    public bool Equals(C1? c) => false;
}

public struct C2 : IEquatable<C2>
{
    public bool Equals(C2 c) => false;
}
```

https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4GIB2BXANliwtwAEcaeBAsAFBUACATAIxW0DMh9hAwg4SIQJIBRAI4YIMMnAA83AHxUA3lUIr2bYAHsNWQiLFYoACm4B+QgGMAlIQC8swgDMIBuAG4qAX2aUabWAgxzGC46XgE9cUkZOnlKJUpVNUJNbV1RZyNOUKtbeycXd0ovSiA=